# Can you bound a JComponent by the center instead of the upper left?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm trying to position some `JButton` objects, but I need the coordinates to position them in terms of the center of the button, instead of the upper left hand corner as default, is there a way to do this?

```
        //Button L1 (Left 1)
   buttonL1 = new JButton( "Button L1" ); 
   buttonL1.setBounds( 150, 140, (int) rWidth, (int) rHeight );
   c.add( buttonL1);

   //Button L2 (Left 2)
   buttonL2 = new JButton( "Button L2" ); 
   buttonL2.setBounds( 150, 340, (int) rWidth, (int) rHeight); 
   c.add( buttonL2 );

   //Button R3 (Right 3)
   buttonR3 = new JButton( "Button R3" ); 
   buttonR3.setBounds( 580, 140, (int) rWidth, (int) rHeight); 
   c.add( buttonR3 );

   //Button R4 (Right 4)
   buttonR4 = new JButton( "Button R4" ); 
   buttonR4.setBounds( 580, 340, 20, 20 ); 
   c.add( buttonR4 );
```

[image: For example, the bottom right button is positioned in terms of the top left hand corner, I need the coordinates I've given all my buttons to be the centre of where they get positioned]

Comment: Yeah use `GridBagLayout` without constraints. But still the requirement is somewhat unclear, please elaborate a bit further

Comment: The only (good) answer you will get is to use a Layout Manager of some kind. Which will depend on what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: May you please eleborate on what to put in center. The line __"I'm trying to position some Jbuttons, but I need the coordinates to position them in terms of the centre of the button, instead of the upper left hand corner as default"__, is a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing to explain. I'm trying to get the coordinates to represent the centre of the button, and not the upper left. Therefore, when the buttons change in size (part of the program) they will all be aligned.

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` (or `GridBagLayout`) with padding to align the buttons.  As mentioned by @nIcEcOw to center a component within its own area of a layout, add a `JPanel` with `GridBagLyout` and add the `JButton` as the only component with no constraint, and it will be centered within that space.  –  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This layout can be achieved using a series of containers with `GridBagLayout` to center the buttons  – with each of those containers going inside a `GridLayout` to align the buttons into columns and rows.

[image] [image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class CenteredButtons {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    CenteredButtons() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        // adjust numbers to need for minimum size/padding etc.
        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,40,10));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
        Insets margin = new Insets(10, 15, 10, 15);

        for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Button " + i);
            btn.setMargin(margin);
            p.add(btn);
            ui.add(p);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                CenteredButtons o = new CenteredButtons();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Centered Buttons");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```